# Where is .bashrc file located in WSL?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Being a completely newcomer in linux world, I'm trying to make some development using ubuntu features. I wanted to add some alias to .bashrc but couldn't find it.
There is an answer on this qustion, but its not a duplicate, because while working on an older versions of windows on my 1803 system it's doesn't work.

Comment: On Linux systems, `.bashrc` is found in the user's home directory.  `~/.bashrc` or `"${HOME}"/.bashrc` or `/home/username/.bashrc`.  Many file explorers hide files beginning with a `.`, and treat them as hidden files.

Comment: How did you try finding it? What answer are you referring to, and how doesn't it work?

Comment: Did you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/40820822/4518341

Comment: Yes, I saw this post. On my system just isn't Lxss folder. I found it with opening home/username directory in VIM. Bash not shows content of this folder. And after earthmeLon told me about hidden files I decided to open entire folder in VIM, and it works) Thank you.